# Suppress a warning from OCaml in a specific line

Tags: ocaml

I am currently building a project, that allows different types of functions, with a different amount of arguments (but all of them of the same type). To define those functions, I used this code for each of them:

```
let {name} [a; b; {...}] =
  {...}
```

My code around that ensures that the number of elements in the list is right, and I'd be fine with just a runtime error occurring if this isn't the case. But I am stuck with a warning, that I'd like to hide because I am aware of this pattern matching being non-exhaustive, and I don't want to see warnings that don't warn me in regards to real errors I have made.

On the other hand: If a language like Dafny (from Microsoft) exists, that is functional, I'd be happy to try that one.

Edit: If there isn't a way to do that, please answer stating exactly that. In that case, I'd build a command line tool that filters out those warnings. (But that would sadly erase all the formatting done...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the other hand: If a language like Dafny (from Microsoft) exists, that is functional, I'd be happy to try that one.

OCaml's type system is powerful enough to express this type of invariant: you can define length-indexed lists by using GADTs.

You have to start by introducing type-level natural numbers:

```
type zero    = Zero
type 'a succ = Succ
```

They're not exactly type-level natural numbers because you can write non-sensical expressions like `int list succ` but they're close enough for our purpose: the data constructors of our type of length-indexed lists will enforce that the length is only made up of `succ`s and a `zero` at the end. I also had to give each of these types a constructor for [reasons outside the scope of this answer](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2013-10/msg00190.html).

You can then define `('a, 'n) vector` the type of `'a list`s which are exactly of length `'n` like so:

```
type ('a, _) vector =
  | []   : ('a, zero) vector
  | (::) : 'a * ('a, 'n) vector -> ('a, 'n succ) vector
```

By using `[]` and `(::)` as constructors, you get to reuse the `list` syntax when defining `param`. I wish it were possible to write `(int, 4) vector` but I couldn't find a way to do so.

```
let param : (int, zero succ succ succ succ) vector = [3;1;0;4]
```

Alternatively, you can let OCaml infer that parameter as in `param_`. You're not stating explicitly the invariant but it'll be checked at each point of use.

```
let param_ : (int, _) vector = [3;1;0;4]
let () = match param_ with
 (*  [x;y;z] -> print "Argh!\n" (* This doesn't typecheck *)*)
  [x;y;z;t] -> print_string "Yeah!\n"
```

Comment: This is neat, but how do you convert those to lists to this type and the other way around? Another thing: I don't like "replacing" lists, but you are effectively doing that (but this can be avoided, I'd guess). Another thing: How is the type definition you were using for `('a, _) vector` called?

Comment: @CodingLambdas I've uploaded [a commented gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/b34b975805e76e273dd64532401116e6) explaining how to convert back and forth. Obviously the conversion should only happen once: there is no point in erasing information only to recover it later by using a runtime check!

These definitions where a constructor can constrain its return type are called [Generalized Algebraic DataTypes (GADTs)](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc85).

Comment: Thanks! I'll just read the gist and the site you linked, hopefully I'll understand it.

Answer (score 11):

As you most likely know, you can write something like this:

```
let name = function
    | [a; b; ... ] -> { ... }
    | _ -> failwith "not possible"
```

But you can (if you insist) disable the warning by writing `[@warning "-8"]` between the `let` and the function name.

```
$ cat warn.ml
let f [a; b] = a + b
$ ocamlc -c warn.ml
File "warn.ml", line 1, characters 6-20:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
(_::_::_::_|_::[]|[])

$ cat nowarn.ml
let [@warning "-8"] f [a; b] = a + b
$ ocamlc -c nowarn.ml
$
```

**Update**

I found a way to turn warnings back on for the body of the function, though it's clunky looking:

```
$ cat semiwarn.ml
let [@warning "-8"] f [a; b] =
    begin [@warning "+8"]
    let a' =
    match a with
        | 0 -> 14
        | 1 -> 15
    in
    a' + b
    end
$ ocamlc -c semiwarn.ml
File "semiwarn.ml", line 4, characters 4-52:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
2
```

As you can see, there is a warning for the match in the body of the function, but not for the function parameters.

On balance this seems a little too cluttered to be a good option if you expect people to be reading the code.

Comment: I know I could use `let name = function` in this specific case, but most of the time there are other arguments supplied (before and) after the list. And adding a `match list with ...` just doesn't look good. And even with `let name = function` it wouldn't be that readable. `let name [a; b] = ...` is something you directly understand.

A question I have to ask: Does the `[@warning "-8"]` suppress the warnings in the whole function, or just in the arguments? Because the first option wouldn't be that great...

Comment: My guess is that it turns off the warning for the whole function. You can probably turn it back on for the inside of the function if you know what you're doing. There is a lot of detail of the handling of attributes that I haven't mastered. Check the [documentation for attributes](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec245).